# LI append SPAN element

Tags: javascript, append

I have a small problem with JavaScript/AppendChild.
So i have navigation designed as :

```
 <ul class = 'child_ul general_ul'>
      <li><a href='#'>Theme 1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Theme 2</a></li> 
  </ul>
```

And I want to append this one inside all LIs:

```
<span class = 'arrow'><i class = 'fa  fa-angle-left'></i></span>
```

This code did't work:

```
var arrow = "<span class = 'arrow'><i class = 'fa  fa-angle-left'></i></span>";

var li_list = document.querySelector('.child_ul > li');

 li_list.appendChild(arrow);
```

Can anyone help me? :)

Comment: I think you need `querySelectorAll`, then loop over the node list.

Comment: `var li_list = document.querySelectorAll('.child_ul > li');
for (var i=0;i<li_list.length;i++) li_list[i].innerHTML+=arrow;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want querySelectorAll (to get all LIs) and innerHTML or createElement

```js
var arrow = "<span class='arrow'><i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i></span>"

var li_list = document.querySelectorAll('.child_ul > li');
for (var i=0;i<li_list.length;i++) {
  li_list[i].innerHTML+=arrow; // += concatenates to the LI
}

// show the html for verification
console.log(document.querySelector(".child_ul").innerHTML)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />


<ul class='child_ul general_ul'>
  <li><a href='#'>Theme 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Theme 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

appendChild needs a CLONED dom fragment like this:

```js
var arrowSpan = document.createElement("span");
arrowSpan.className = "arrow"
arrowSpan.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>" // or more createElements

var li_list = document.querySelectorAll('.child_ul > li');
for (var i = 0; i < li_list.length; i++) {
  li_list[i].appendChild(arrowSpan.cloneNode(true));
}

// show the html for verification
console.log(document.querySelector(".child_ul").innerHTML)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />


<ul class='child_ul general_ul'>
  <li><a href='#'>Theme 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Theme 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: First thanks for comment. innerHTML removes the real text of LI. But i dont want do this. I want to add this span to inside Li.

Comment: innerHTML `+=` !!! does not remove anything. Please look closer at my code

Comment: @jahangir_kazimli, you can print out the innerHTML for <ul>, then you will see the result above is correct. like console.log(document.querySelector('.child_ul').innerHTML)